# Ubuntu 20.04 on Acer Aspire XC-603: Keyboard Problem?

Tags: keyboard

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 OK on the Acer Aspire XC-603, wiping out Win 8.1 (completely?), and I have now disabled Secure Boot in the BIOS (P11-B1).
When I try to Sign In to Ubuntu One to get to Snap Store (on the Acer), I can not enter underscore in my E Mail name (it puts in a dash) and I can not enter @ in my E Mail name (it puts in a 2).
I am using the Shift key in both cases.
Likewise with my password, which has upper and lower case letters: it may not be going in correctly.
I am not sure why this is happening.

Here is a screenshot of the output when I ran the terminal command "setxkbmap -query".[image: .PNG screenshot of output for terminal command "setxkbmap -query"]

Comment: Can you run this in terminal *setxkbmap -query* and add the output to your question by editing it? That may help.